SQL to tell if string is numeric characters followed by alphabetic characters
Is it possible to determine if a string is numeric characters followed by alphabetic characters?
E.g. "123AB" is valid, "4.5 CD" is also valid, "CDE3" is not. "4d9" is invalid.
declare @t table (my_string varchar(10))

insert @t 
select '1.23bc' union -- Valid
select '4 d' union -- Valid
select 'a1' -- Invalid

select 'my_magic_expression' 
from @t

Desired output:

Yes
Yes
No


Why is 2CDE not valid? That's a numerical character (2) followed by alpha characters (CDE).

Would you ever have a pattern like 4d9? If so, would you consider that valid or not?

Oops @ThomA corrected thanks

By "numeric characters", do you mean digits from 0-9 only or also other signs that might belong to a number as for example a dot?

4d9 is Invalid, Clarification added @Isolated

@JonasMetzler decimals are allowed. e.g. 1.5G is allowed

Ok, but .5G would not be allowed?

Is this the correct interpretation: Starts numeric (decimals ok) followed ONLY  by alpha.

I see the ball game has changed between when I wrote a code solution and completed my testing & wrote an explanation for posting it... The requirements and the post are clearly in conflict at this point...

Would '-17e5 abc' be "valid" too..? It starts with a valid number (-1700000 as a exponent) followed by only alpha characters.

Seeing the comment section this questions clearly needs an update with all cases included

This isn't particularly easily in T-SQL; it doesn't have support for Regex, only redimentary pattern matching. That being said you could achieve these by checking the following "rules" are true:

The string starts with a number and ends with a letter.
The string only contains numbers, letters, and spaces.
That the only characters that appear after the first non-number character are letters and spaces.

This gives something like the following:
DECLARE @t table (MyString varchar(10));

INSERT INTO @t (MyString)
VALUES('123AB'),
      ('45 CD'),
      ('3CDE'),
      ('123bc'),
      ('4 d'),
      ('CDE3'),
      ('4d9'),
      ('a1');

SELECT CASE WHEN MyString LIKE '[0-9]%[A-z]'
             AND MyString NOT LIKE '%[^0-9 A-z]%'
             AND STUFF(MyString,1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]',MyString),'') NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END,
       MyString
FROM @t;

The code solution was written before the comments which denote that more than number and letter characters are valid. This answer is based on the post at the time the answer was written, which is likely to now change.

You did answer the original question, thank you. I can run with your answer, it's given me the insights I needed

This would guarantee that you have both numerics and alphabetics and that none appear out of the desired order:
    my_string     like '%[0-9]%[A-Z]%' -- outer wildcards might not be needed here
and my_string not like '%[A-Z]%[0-9]%'

For simplicity I used only capital letters. Add in other character ranges as necessary. There might be some other yet unstated rules like whether a . can appear more than once and where spaces are valid. This expression needs to be expanded for more restrictive filtering.
https://dbfiddle.uk/woME8gI7

Not sure this is right: '1&apple4b' would be an "acceptable" string with that.
